# Emulating HTTP POST using command line curl and exporting output to text file

Tags: php, arrays, curl

How do I emulate an HTTP POST request using curl and capturing the result on a text file? I already have a script called dump.php:

```
<?php
  $var = print_r($GLOBALS, true);
  $fp = fopen('raw-post.txt','w');
  fputs($fp,$var);
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

I did a simple test by doing:

```
curl -d 'echo=hello' http://localhost/dump.php
```

but I didn't see the data I dumped in the output file. I was expecting it to appear in one of the POST arrays but it's empty.

```
[_POST] => Array
    (
    )

[HTTP_POST_VARS] => Array
    (
    )
```

Comment: As suggested by Evan, changed this to $_GLOBALS instead of $GLOBALS and now there's no output

Comment: Removed the tick marks in the curl -d option and now the POST variables are visible in the output file. Thanks Evan for the help!

Comment: You're welcome Francis, sorry I didn't know the problem though. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$_GLOBALS` rather than `$GLOBALS`.

Additionally, you can do this instead of using output buffering:

```
$var = print_r($_GLOBALS, true);
```

Providing the `true` as a second parameter to `print_r` will return the result rather than automatically printing it.

Comment: Change it to $_GLOBALS but got no output

Answer (score 1):

Remove tick marks (') from the curl command line:

```
curl -d hello=world -d test=yes http://localhost/dump.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to capture POST data, then do something like this for you `dump.php` file.

```
<?php
    $data = print_r($_POST, true);
    $fp = fopen('raw-post.txt','w');
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

All POST data is stored in the `$_POST` variable. Additionally, if you need GET data as well, `$_REQUEST` will hold both.

Comment: Replaced $_GLOBALS with $_REQUEST and the output is:

    Array
    (
    )

Comment: $_GLOBALS would have included both _POST and _GET arrays but it contains nothing when I do the curl command above.